# Scheme code doesn't work

Tags: scheme, sicp

I have some code that is supposed to take a list and return the reverse of that list. However, it just returns the list. Here is the code

```
(define (reverse listx)
  (define (thing list1 list2)
    (if (null? list1)
        list2
        (thing (cdr list1) (append list2 (list (car list1))))
        )
    )
  (thing listx nil)
  )
```

The problem I think hinges on the fact that

```
 (append nil 1) => 1
```

rather than

```
 (append nil 1) => (1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not it: you do call `(append list2 (list ...))`, with the 2nd arg enclosed in a `list`.

The problem is that you use `append` while you ought to use simple `cons` there: `(thing (cdr list1) (cons (car list1) list2))`.

With `cons`, each new element from `list1` will go *on top* (i.e. "to the left of") the previously handled ones, hence building the result *in reverse*:

```
(a b c d e)
--------------------------
(a b c d e)             ()
  (b c d e)            (a)
    (c d e)          (b a)
      (d e)        (c b a)
        (e)      (d c b a)
         ()    (e d c b a)
--------------------------
               (e d c b a)
```

But with `append` you're just recreating the same list.

Comment: Of course, I was getting confused with the whacking on of elements. Thank you very much

Comment: I don't think append is the problem so much as the order of arguments to it, though it's true cons is the preferred procedure here.